# How to make all warnings an error

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, pragma, xc8

In section 3.14.4.9.2 of the *MPLAB XC8 C Compiler User's Guide* it states that when using the `warning` directive the compiler will tread the given warning like an error and cease compilation, e. g.

```
#pragma warning error 123
```

**How to force this behaviour for all type of warnings?**

I tried `#pragma warning error` and `#pragma warning error all` but it did'nt work.

Comment: did you try in project>properties>xc8 compiler the warning level section?

Comment: @B_PRIEUR tried just now, but what does that do? Apparently just gives more or less warnings dependend on their level?!

Comment: that's true, I didn't try it, sry, I am searching right now

Comment: well... xc32 gcc compiler has an option make warnings into errors that generates command line argument -Werror but xc8 doesn't accept it so I guess you can't